# jQuery Select first and second td

Tags: jquery

How can I add a class to the first and second td in each tr?

```
<div class='location'>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>THIS ONE</td>
<td>THIS ONE</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>THIS ONE</td>
<td>THIS ONE</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

For the first td, this does nothing?

```
$(".location table tbody tr td:first-child").addClass("black");
```

Can I also use second-child?

Comment: [It looks like your code should work.](http://jsfiddle.net/hr5gT/)

Comment: It just selects the very first td, not subsequent ones.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
$(".location table tbody tr td:first-child").addClass("black");
$(".location table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("black");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/68wbx/1/

Comment: I had a table that was into a <form />, not a div and it didn't work.

Comment: @Misi as long as the `<form />` tag has a class of location added, it should work. `<form class='location'>...</form>`

Answer (score 22):

To select the first and the second cell in each row, you could do this:

```
$(".location table tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).children('td').slice(0, 2).addClass("black");
});
```

Comment: I like the `slice()` because it makes it slightly cleaner than James Montagne's solution.

Comment: I like the one call of this, even though 2 call is simpler looking (voted for both). I keep getting caught by slice(start, end) excludes the "end" one. 0, 2 (just like you have it) means the 1st and the 2nd. (not 1st through 3rd).

Answer (score 10):

You can do in this way also

```
var prop = $('.someProperty').closest('tr');
```

If the number of tr is in array

```
$.each(prop , function() {
  var gotTD = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');                 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".location table tbody tr").each(function(){
    $('td:first', this).addClass('black').next().addClass('black');
});
```

another:

```
$(".location table tbody tr").find('td:first, td:nth-child(2)').addClass('black');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a class to the first **and** second td you can use `.each()` and `slice()`

```
$(".location table tbody tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td").slice(0, 2).addClass("black");
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/wm735/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

#### jquery provides one more function: eq

### Select first tr

$(".bootgrid-table tr").eq(0).addClass("black");

### Select second tr

$(".bootgrid-table tr").eq(1).addClass("black");

Answer (score 0):

You can just pick the next td:

```
$(".location table tbody tr td:first-child").next("td").addClass("black");
```