# Jquery to Change the width of td in table inside a div

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have the following html how can i access the first table's td and change the width to 40%  and 60% respectively using Jquery

```html
 <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
        <a id="mainContent" tabindex="-1" name="mainContent"></a>
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="15%" valign="top"></td>
                    <td width="85%" valign="top"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width="100%"></table>
        <table width="100%"></table>
     </div>
```

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588265/jquery-select-first-and-second-td)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, hope this help :

```js
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain table')
  .find('tr td')
  .first()
  .attr('width','40%')
  .next()
    .attr('width','60%');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
        <a id="mainContent" tabindex="-1" name="mainContent"></a>
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="15%" valign="top">a</td>
                    <td width="85%" valign="top">b</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width="100%"></table>
        <table width="100%"></table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hi Norlihazmey Thanks for your answer its not working may be becasue i am using IE 8 which jquery 2.1.1 doesn't support as it throws error on .first() is their any other way to access it using Jquery 1.11.0 version

Comment: What about change `.find('tr td')` into `.find('tr td:first')` or `.find('tr td:nth-child(1)')`, then remove `.first()` function.

Comment: If also did't work change into `.find('tr td').eq(0)`, also remove `.first()` function.

Comment: Thanks Norlihazmey i tired the following and it worked .although its slow while page laoding.
$("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain table").find("tr td").eq(0).attr("width","40%");
$("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain table").find("tr td").eq(1).attr("width","60%");

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain > table:first-child > tbody > tr td:first-child").attr("width", "40%");
$("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain > table:first-child > tbody > tr td:last-child").attr("width", "60%");
```

Try this if it works though. I haven't tested it yet.
The idea here is to make use of first-child/last-child/nth-child() selectors to achieve the desired result.

Please reply if this did not work so I could help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain').find('table').first().find('td').first().attr('width','60%')
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain').find('table').first().find('td').last().attr('width','40%')
```