# Find Table TD value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, find

I have a 'search' function for my HTML table which is populated from a database. I have the following code which is activated through a button and a text box with the ID entered.

I am trying to get the next/second TD in that rows text/value. I can successfully get the first TD but not the second. Any ideas?

```js
function search() {
  var valueToFind = $('#EnterSiteNo').val();

  $('#SiteTable > tbody> tr').each(function(index) {
    var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first');
    var secondTd = $(this).find('td:second');

    if ($(firstTd).text() == valueToFind) {
      var name = secondTd.text();
      alert("found. " + name);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try `td:nth-child()` instead of `:second`

So here you should change your code to

```
var secondTd = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `td:nth-child(2)` as the selector.

[jQuery Select first and second td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588265/jquery-select-first-and-second-td)